# Calculate progress based on a number range, php.

Tags: php, css, joomla, progress-bar

I am currently developing an experience bar and I'm stuck on this last step. I'm pulling the current user information from the database (user id, xp value, group id) and then displaying the users progress in a progress bar using two CSS styled divs. The part I'm stuck on is that the variable $fullBar is not a static amount. I have the leveling system set up using user groups in Joomla. If the current users group id = 10, $fullBar = 9. If the user group id = 11, $fullBar should be a range from 10-99. If the current users group id = 12, $fullBar should be a range from 100-999. Essentially, the amount the percentage is being calculated from changes depending on what level the user is. I've tried using calculations such as $userXp/(999-100) * 100 for a user with id 12, for instance...but then, if the users xp is approaching 999 it actually returns a value greater than 100%. I'm not the greatest with math so if someone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div id="xpBar">

<?php

$user = JFactory::getUser();
$userId = $user->id;
$userXp = $user->userxp;
$groups = $user->get('groups');
foreach($groups as $group);

$fullBar = 999;

$percentage = function($userXp, $fullBar, $precision) 
{
$res = round( ($userXp / $fullBar) * 100, $precision );
return $res;
};

?>

<div id="percent" style="width: <?php echo $percentage($userXp, $fullBar, 0); ?>%"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: So, converted into percentage, the desired outcome of xp `999` would be 99%?

Comment: Yes. In the event that $group = 12, then 100 should be 0% and 999 should be 99%. Then when the user levels up, the bar resets. Basically, I want the progress bar to base the percentage off of whatever xp range they are in.

Comment: try this http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#progress